# Constant noise in headphones

Tags: 14.04, sound, alsa, headphones

Today a new problem cropped up in my HP Probook 430 G3 with Ubuntu 14.04. I noticed that my earphones and speakers were simultaneously playing so I tried out various options from here on AskUbuntu threads like Auto-mute options in alsamixer and gnome-alsamixer. I also tried to add the following to **alsa-base.conf** and restarted.

```
options snd-hda-intel model=laptop
options snd-hda-intel position_fix=1 enable=yes
```

After restart all sorts of problems started with weird static and beeps at startup so I removed these lines and restarted. Now on reboot there is a static on speakers for about 3-5 secs before the Ubuntu boot animation and then it goes away. Now whenever I plug in my earphones there will be a constant static, no sound from speakers and no response to changing anything on alsamixer like volume levels or mic boost or anything else.

I have tried reinstalling **alsa-utils** using apt-get but to no avail.

[image]

Comment: If it's a static sound, It's HP. No doubt about it. I had a HP Stream 7, and when I used Headphones, There was always static noise. Even when I installed Puppy Linux on it.

Comment: It wasn't present before I tried the actions I mentioned above. It isn't just a static in the background. It is a very piercing white noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem has gone away now. At least it has not surfaced since last 5 restarts. It was solved by a combination of steps mentioned in the question and restarting at each step.